# Calling custom tagLib inside another custom tagLib dynamically

Tags: grails, dynamic, gsp, taglib

I have made two custom tagLibs, namely tabContainer and tab.

```
def tabContainer = { attrs, body ->
    println("body: "+body())
    out << '<div class="tab-content">' << body() << '</div>'
}
```

and

```
def tab = { attrs, body ->
    out << '<div class="tab-pane '+${attrs.active == "true" ? "active" : ""}+'" id="'+attrs.id+'">' << body() << '</div>'
}
```

Now I want to insert the tab inside tabContainer as many times the user specifies inside GSP page like-

```
<myUI:tabContainer>
    <myUI:tab id="hello1">Hello1 contents</myUI:tab>
    <myUI:tab id="hello2" active="true">Hello2 contents</myUI:tab>
</myUI:tabContainer>
```

Now if I do that then comes the following error-

`Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <myUI:tabContainer>: Error executing tag <myUI:tab>: No signature of method: myui.myUITagLib.$() is applicable for argument types: (myui.myUITagLib$_closure14_closure15) values: [myui.myUITagLib$_closure14_closure15@2090a569]`

**Need: Any number of `tab` can be passed inside `tabcontainer` as passed by the user on a GSP page.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your tab tag like this .It working for me.

```
out << '<div class="tab-pane ' + (attrs.active == "true" ? 'active' : '') + '" id="' + attrs.id + '">' << body() << '</div>'
```